# How to add < in TextInput. To show message like < Back

Tags: react-native

how can i insert < in TextInput. I want to show message like < Back.

I tried entering the < directly but it gives compile time error.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the text with brackets like that:

```
<Text>{'< Back'}</Text>
```